# Is there a card game software that can play with real cards?

Tags: game, camera, tablet

I prefer to play with real cards than on the computer (not to mention my grandchildren!), but sometimes there aren't enough people for a game. I wonder why no one has yet made a software to which you can show its hand (without you seeing them, like turning the cards towards the device's camera), and then the AI would tell you each time what it does by observing the game through its camera, and it would instruct you, like play the 2nd card from top of the hand.

Is there such a software?